# Loading more complex SVG as background image

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I have an input field with a SVG background image. This works like a charm, the image is showing:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="%239a5371"><path d="M14.5 8h-0.5v-1.5c0-2.481-2.019-4.5-4.5-4.5s-4.5 2.019-4.5 4.5v1.5h-0.5c-0.827 0-1.5 0.673-1.5 1.5v8c0 0.827 0.673 1.5 1.5 1.5h10c0.827 0 1.5-0.673 1.5-1.5v-8c0-0.827-0.673-1.5-1.5-1.5zM6 6.5c0-1.93 1.57-3.5 3.5-3.5s3.5 1.57 3.5 3.5v1.5h-7v-1.5zM15 17.5c0 0.276-0.224 0.5-0.5 0.5h-10c-0.276 0-0.5-0.224-0.5-0.5v-8c0-0.276 0.224-0.5 0.5-0.5h10c0.276 0 0.5 0.224 0.5 0.5v8z"></path></svg>');
```

But this does NOT work:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48px" height="48px"><g transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"> <path stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#444444" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M24,2L24,2 c-5.5,0-10,4.5-10,10v6h20v-6C34,6.5,29.5,2,24,2z"></path> <rect stroke-linejoin="round" x="8" y="18" fill="none" stroke="#444444" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="32" height="28"></rect> <circle stroke-linejoin="round" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#444444" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="24" cy="30" r="4"></circle> <line stroke-linejoin="round" data-color="color-2" fill="none" stroke="#444444" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="24" y1="34" x2="24" y2="38"></line> </g></svg>');
```

The second one is a little more complex, but not THAT much, hm? Can someone tell me why this is not loaded? (firebug says image could not be loaded).

**EDIT:** Sorry I was dumb, it was the hex color. Now it's working with something like "%239a5371" instead of "#9a5371".

Comment: Also, to make this work on IE you might have to URL encode the svg. The benefit is that URL encoded SVG strings work anywhere, not just IE.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305437/svg-datauri-in-css-not-working-in-firefox